# Reading From OGR error in c++

Tags: c++, centos, gdal

I'm trying to compile the following code using the gdal libraries in Centos 7:

The name of the file is rungdal.cpp

```
#include "/usr/include/gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h"
int main(){
    // Register all format drivers
    GDALAllRegister();
}
```

I run the program using: g++ rungdal.cpp -o rungdal, and I have the following message:

error: ‘GDALAllRegister’ was not declared in this scope

I also include the whole path from the header file, if I don't use it the program doesn't work, maybe it's something related.

What can I do for executing the program?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does including `gdal_priv.h` fix the problem? Here's the [OGR tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) which does the same.

Comment: the include syntax is expected to be: `#include <gdal/gdal.h>` in order to have the `GDALAllRegister()` declared.

Comment: I tried with both headers: gdal_priv.h and gdal.h, in both cases I have the message: undefined reference to `GDALAllRegister'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the code with your suggestions:

```
#include <gdal/gdal.h>

int main(){
    // Register all format drivers
    GDALAllRegister();  
}
```

In addition, I have to add the line -lgdal for the compilation and it works.

g++ rungdal.cpp -o rungdal -lgdal

Thanks for your help!

Alvaro

Comment: Works too using: #include <gdal/gdal_priv.h>